# Relations between distributions

Tags: distributions

Note that there are some distributions that can be derived from the others (continuous as well as discrete).

For example student and chi-square distribution are derived from normal distribution and binomial distribution can be derived from Bernoulli distribution.

Of course, the term "derived" can be understood in two ways - directly derived (for example normal - student) or using some limit (binomial - poisson).

Is there any diagram depicting these kind of relation? If not, it is possible to draw it with at least the most known discrete and continuous distributions? I would prefer graph with nodes as distributions and directed edges that would mean that one distribution can be derived from another (limit cases should be also depicted).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

http://www.johndcook.com/distribution_chart.html

Comment: Great answer! Note also recommended publication in that site with [exhaustive diagram](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

A fairly complete graph is given in

"Univariate Distribution Relationships" Lawrence M. Leemis and Jacquelyn T. McQueston *The American Statistician* 2008, vol. 62 n. 1 pp. 45-53.

Comment: Isnt't it the same publication as in my comment to @SamLivingstone?

Comment: Yes it is the same ;)